# Is there a way to display data "decoded" when selecting from a table in MySql Database?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I'm  working on a project database that has names stored in database in one column as a json containing the English and Arabic description.
When using PhpMyAdmin, I find it very difficult to read the data from a select statement because Arabic is encoded

[image]

Is there a way to see the output or select result in a readable format right away??

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? If it's 8.x, you can use the JSON functions to extract the name into a normal string.

Comment: Erm, json **is** readable without any additional formatting. If you want to transform json values, then you need to specify how the output should look like.

Comment: @Shadow, look at the Arabic

Comment: @Barmar, how can I tell the version?

Comment: That's not an issue with json, that's an encoding or display problem. Since some of the English text seems to have character codes instead of text, I would venture, you made a mistake while inserting the data into mysql.

Comment: @Shadow, there is no issue with the json, I want a way to display it "decoded"

Comment: @AbeerSul https://geeksww.com/tutorials/database_management_systems/mysql/tips_and_tricks/how_to_check_mysql_version_number.php#phpmyadmin

Comment: I don't think your json is correct, otherwise phpmyadmin would display some kind of letters instead of character codes. Json is after all a string containing an internal structure.